# Rails why do I need to add in current_user.id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have in my navigation code where it checks if a user is admin or not. I want the path to do be `admin_path` to go to the `index` but I get an error `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin"}, missing required keys: [:id]` if I don't put `admin_path(current_user.id)` why is that needed or how can I fix that so it will go to the index?

nav_bar code

```
<% elsif current_user && current_user.admin? %>
        <ul class='navbar-nav ml-auto'>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <%= link_to 'Dashboard', admin_path(current_user.id), class: "nav-link" %>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

admin_Controller

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user_as_admin

  def index
   
  end

  def show
  
  end

  private
  def authenticate_user_as_admin
    authenticate_user!
    if !current_user.admin?
      redirect_to root_path if !current_user.admin?
      flash[:alert] = "Sorry #{current_user.first_name} #{current_user.last_name} you don't have permission to visit this page"
    end
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
 resources :admin
```

Comment: Your link in navigation  admin_path is pointing to the show action so show action require an Id to locate the resource. You can run rake routes in the terminal and see what is the correct path for index. It will probably be something like admins_path

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of the `resources` macro is to create a set of RESTful CRUD routes for a resource.

The route you're declaring is not a resource. And thats OK. But you really just want to define it as a simple GET route:

```
get :admin, as: :admin_dashboard, 
            to: 'admins#dashboard'
```

```
# Don't repeat yourself
class ApplicationController
  helper_method :admin?
  def admin?
    current_user&.admin?
  end
end
```

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorize_admin!

  # GET /admin
  def dashboard
  end

  private

  def authorize_admin!
    authenticate_user!
    unless admin?
      flash[:alert] = "Sorry #{current_user.first_name} #{current_user.last_name} you don't have permission to visit this page"
      redirect_to root_path 
    end
  end
end
```

```
<% elsif admin? %>
  <ul class='navbar-nav ml-auto'>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <%= link_to 'Dashboard', admin_dashboard_path, class: "nav-link" %>
    </li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Note that there is a huge difference between **authenticating** the user - which is verifying that the users identity and **authorizing** which is determening if the user should be able to perform a given action. For the later you might want to look into gems like Pundit and CanCanCan.